# Using Ansible "find" to find files in directory that match

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use "find" to find all files in a directory with certain filenames, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
- hosts: all

  tasks:
  - name: "Ansible | Print a variable"
    debug:
      msg: "The play_tomcat_dest_dir is {{ play_tomcat_dest_dir }}"

  - name: Delete any mysql-connector-java-*.jar files
    find:
      paths: "{{ play_tomcat_dest_dir }}lib"
      patterns: "mysql-connector-java-*.jar"
      use_regex: true
    register: wildcard_files_to_delete

  - name: "Ansible | Print a variable"
    debug:
      msg: "The wildcard_files_to_delete is {{ wildcard_files_to_delete }}"
```

The play_tomcat_dest_dir is:

```
/apps/apache-tomcat-9.0.54/
```

and "/apps/apache-tomcat-9.0.54/lib" directory has at least one "mysql-connector-java-...jar" file.

But when I run this playbook (using ansible-playbook) I am getting:

```
PLAY [all]     **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test_host]

TASK [Ansible | Print a variable] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test_host] => {
"msg": "The play_tomcat_dest_dir is /apps/apache-tomcat-9.0.54/"
}

TASK [Delete any mysql-connector-java-*.jar files] ******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test_host]

TASK [Ansible | Print a variable] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test_host] => {
"msg": "The wildcard_files_to_delete is {u'files': [], u'changed': False, 'failed': False, u'examined': 55, u'msg': u'', u'matched': 0}"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
test_host                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with the "find"?

Thanks!  Jim

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/5070/how-do-i-get-the-find-module-to-work-in-ansible

I commented out the "use_regex" line, and then it worked :)!!

Comment: The other solution was to transform your pattern to a regex that actually match what you are looking for => `mysql-connector-java-.*.jar`. Your actual pattern as a regex is perfectly valid but you match e.g. `mysql-connector-java.jar`, `mysql-connector-java-------.jar`...